# Smell of urine and urine looking fluid from bathroom vanity

Tags: bathroom, smell, vanity

We renovated our bathroom and over several months  we have noticed a smell of urine which has grown stronger no matter how much I cleaned.  Hubby checked everywhere and all connections good.
I eventually narrowed down the smell to the bathroom vanity/sink (*purchased from Costco*).

I have a handheld steam cleaner and when I applied it where the sink met the countertop the smell worsened as a dark urine colored fluid and some debris came pouring out.   Almost exclusively at the front of the vanity.  It was foul!

I am repeating this steaming every week and get less fluid each time but the smell does build during the week.

What else can I do about it?

Comment: House or condo/apartment? Any possibility that this is coming from above (*i.e.* apartment or condo or first floor of house with fixtures above, possible leak in drain pipe coming from above - or is that not possible (top floor, single level house, etc...)?

Comment: You can include a picture so we better see what's going on. Also, sometimes new materials or adhesives release gasses that to some may smell like something foul.

Comment: That must be the *Euro-pee-an* model.

Comment: How was it plumbed into the sewer system? Was a **trap** used?

Comment: Costco Ove vanities are manufactured in China. I've recently installed two of the higher end models and the glue under the marble top had a smell like urine. Nice vanity otherwise. Hitting it with steam might have broken down some of the adhesive and might explain the increase in odor.